# Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `hotel` on serializer `ResidenceSerializer`

Tags: python, django

```
class Hotel (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    country = models.CharField()
    city = models.CharField()
    street = models.CharField() 


class Residence(models.Model):
    hotel_id = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='hotel')
    house_number = models.CharField()
```

I created two models Hotel and Residence and I want to join them together

```
serializers.py

class HotelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
      model = Hotel
      fields = ['name', 'country', 'city', 'street']


class ResidenceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   hotel = HotelSerializer()

   class Meta:
     model = Residence
     fields = ['house_number', 'hotel']
```

In the serializers.py, I wrote this code

```
 views.py

 class ResidenceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
 serializer_class = ResidenceSerializer
 queryset = Residence.objects.all()
```

In the serializers.py, I wrote this code but when I try to run my code I get this error: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `hotel` on serializer `ResidenceSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Residence` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Residence' object has no attribute 'hotel'.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you do the following changes

```
class ResidenceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   hotel_id = RegisterHotelSerializer()

   class Meta:
     model = Residence
     fields = ['house_number', 'hotel_id']
```

Comment: hi, it worked but when I try to post the data I got anther problem: Residence() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hotel_id' . Can anyonr help me ?

Comment: I added the following code to post:     def create(self, validated_data):
                                                                return Residence.objects.create(**validated_data) but I get a proleem: Residence() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hotel_id'. When I try to post data

Comment: can you write what is the last code for the post and also create a function which in serializer??